# Could not find a 'Kafka Client' entry in the JAAS configuration

Tags: jmeter, jaas, vertx-kafka-client

Firstly, we are trying to send the Kafka messages using this JMeter for sasl_ssl enabled Kafka. So, For that purpose we have created a thread group(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9wzj.png) in that we have added pepper-box plain-text config(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhtTu.png), Pepper-box serialized config(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnKkI.png) and java request(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyEN4.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDR7B.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn8X3.png).

1. Now, we have added the message that we want to send to the consumer in plain-text config.
2. I have loaded the class in serialized config
3. Java request I have added the necessary parameters like bootstrap servers, Kafka topic name, Jaas config and all
   4.Now when we are running the JMeter we are getting the issue like could not find a 'Kafka Client' entry in JAAS Configuration

We were trying to send the Kafka message using JMeter for sasl_ssl enabled Kafka, but it was giving an error called Could not find a 'Kafka Client' entry in the JAAS configuration.
We were expecting to get the message in consumer part. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gchrr.png)

Although we have a Kafka client entry in jaas.config we got the same error for your reference I have attached file as shown in below image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FjBY.png).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `Kafka Client` entry in your `jaas.conf` file, it should look like:

```
Kafka Client {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    serviceName="foo"
    username="bar"
    password="baz";
};
```

or ask your application/network developers/administrators for the proper entry.

More information:

- [Authenticate with SASL using JAAS](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/index.html)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-jmeter) (it's about HTTP Request samplers but the approach should be the same)
- [JMeter + Pepper-Box Plugin for Kafka Performance Testing to Choose or Not to Choose?](https://dzone.com/articles/jmeter-pepper-box-plugin-for-kafka-performance-tes)
- [PepperBoxKafkaSampler](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box/blob/master/README.md#pepperboxkafkasampler)

Comment: We have already added that, but it is still same. For your reference I have added in the above post now you can see there.